# insert into, select and update queries at once

Tags: sql

i have a table named exams with the column names and values

```
Id(PK)- ExamName - GradeId - TermId
155  - Maths - 22 - 15 
156 - English - 23 - 15
```

what i want to do is: to select the row with the id=155, update grade Id to 32 and term id to 25 and insert into the same table. since Id is a primary key, Id will change as well.
so the new inserted row will be:

```
157 - Maths - 32 - 25
```

Is there anyone who can assist me on this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't update Primary Keys. That is bad practice. Why would you want to in this case? You are changing everything about the record. Insert a new one and delete the old one.

Comment: actually, I will not update the primary key, since I am inserting a new record, it is an auto-increment column, a duplicate is not allowed. this is a part of the table, I just give the related columns.

Comment: So you are not doing any updating. You are doing a single insert. What are you having trouble with in doing one insert?

Comment: yes, exactly. 155 should be there. why i need to do this via qurey is my table has thousands of data. and to simplify the question i just told select the roww with id=155. otherwise i will do it via subquery later.

Comment: I am doing an update. and the Id number will be selected by a subquery. and the other update values will be supplied by subqueries. to make the scenario simple i wrote like above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the existing record via:

```
update exams set GradeId = 32, TermId=25 where Id=155
```

Or, you can insert a new record with those values like below, but updating would be more preferrable

```
insert into exams values (157,'Maths',32,25)
```

IF the primary key is auto-incrementing, then you can use:

```
insert into exams (ExamName,GradeId,TermId) values ('Maths',32,25)
```

Never update a primary key, it always creates problems!

EDIT:

To insert a record to a table from another table, please try:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (ExamName,GradeId,TermId) 
SELECT ExamName,GradeId=32,TermID=25 --don't know where the numbers are coming from, that's why adding manually here
FROM examps
WHERE Id = 155
```

Comment: Hi Eray, let me write my problem in Turkish. (Sorry other guys, i need to explain my problem): Elimdeki tabloda tanimlanmis sinavlar var. ve tanimlanan bir sinavi ben bir baska sinifa klonlamak istiyorum. bunu yapmak icin de sectigim Id no lu exam i tablonun sonua tekrar eklemeliyim, ama eklerken de sinif ve term id si de hedef sinif ve term e gore update olcak (ben yukarida manuel id verdim ama onlari da baska sorgudan alarak update etcem. net anlatabildim mi acaba?

Comment: @celoaga edited answer. Since you do not want to perform any update in your original table but the other table you need the data be included, I think you can use an insert query with select like in the answer.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will improve this according to my need.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want `INSERT INTO.. SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO exams (ExamName, GradeId, TermId)
SELECT ExamName, 32, 25
FROM exams
WHERE Id = 155
```

If you plan to reuse this in an automated way, you will want to replace the hardcoded values (`32, 25, 155`) with whatever logic you used to get these.